# Related Rate Question: Two sides of a triangle are 6 m and 8 m in length and the angle between them is increasing at a rate of 0.06 rad/s

Tags: calculus

Two sides of a triangle are 6 m and 8 m in length and the angle between them is increasing at a rate of $0.06$ rad/s. Find the rate at which the area of the triangle is increasing when the angle between the sides of fixed length is $\large\frac {\pi}{3}$ rad.

Answer (score 1):

Express the area using the two sides you know and the angle between them (there's a formula for that). Differentiate with respect to time using the chain rule, knowing that the time derivative of the angle is $0.06$.

Answer (score 1):

It took me some time, but I got the answer. It is 0.72m^2/s.

Comment: You should edit your question to include this information.

Comment: Your answer is correct.